# Replication of solr Lucene index failing with following error message

Tags: java, apache, solr, lucene

I am getting below error when running solr replication

```
2013-12-27 05:03:32,391 [explicit-fetchindex-cmd] ERROR org.apache.solr.handler.ReplicationHandler- SnapPull failed :org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Index fetch failed :
      at org.apache.solr.handler.SnapPuller.fetchLatestIndex(SnapPuller.java:485)
      at org.apache.solr.handler.ReplicationHandler.doFetch(ReplicationHandler.java:319)
      at org.apache.solr.handler.ReplicationHandler$1.run(ReplicationHandler.java:220)
       Caused by: java.io.EOFException: read past EOF: MMapIndexInput(path="/apps/search/data/customers/solr/solr/adidas-archive/data/index.20131227050332242/segments_a")
      at org.apache.lucene.store.ByteBufferIndexInput.readByte(ByteBufferIndexInput.java:78)
      at org.apache.lucene.store.ChecksumIndexInput.readByte(ChecksumIndexInput.java:41)
      at org.apache.lucene.store.DataInput.readInt(DataInput.java:84)
      at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:320)
      at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$1.doBody(SegmentInfos.java:380)
      at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:812)
      at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:663)
      at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.read(SegmentInfos.java:376)
      at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:711)
      at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.<init>(SolrIndexWriter.java:77)
      at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.create(SolrIndexWriter.java:64)
      at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.createMainIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:267)
      at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.newIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:179)
      at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.newIndexWriter(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:632)
      at org.apache.solr.handler.SnapPuller.fetchLatestIndex(SnapPuller.java:469)
      ... 2 more
```

My step-up is Master on 3.x and Slave on 4.x.

This happened when I copied very large index 100 g+. What does this error means ? Does it means that index has got corrupt and if so what can be done to fix it, any thoughts ?

I ran the checkindex utility, but is again giving the error :

```
ERROR: could not read any segments file in directory
java.io.EOFException: read past EOF: MMapIndexInput(path="/apps/search/data/customers/solr/solr/adidas-archive/data/index.20131227051833263/segments_a") at  org.apache.lucene.store.ByteBufferIndexInput.readByte(ByteBufferIndexInput.java:78)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.ChecksumIndexInput.readByte(ChecksumIndexInput.java:41)
```

Answer (score 0):

while upgrading the version of solr3.x to 4.x to upgrade you can use any of the following methods
1 . rebuild the index from scratch (time taking)
OR
2.  optimize the index

But What i found in upgrading  from 3.6 to 4.2 was that if your index size in more than 100 gigs (mine was over 170 gigs in solr 3.6 ) .It would be more fruitful to rebuild the index from scratch as new compression techniques are implemented now . (my index size got reduced from 170 gigs to 115 gigs  in solr 4.2). other wise after optimization your index would be accepted by solr 4.x . but index size would remain same .

Please don't use different versions in a same replication system .
If you have been using it in past please share the details it would be really helpful

regards

rajat

Comment: Ok, but can please tell me what could cause this error to occur and what needs to be done to mitigate this ?

Comment: install a 4.x solr on your master machine . start it using indexing directory of older version  (shutdown old one first ) . optimize the index, it might do the trick

Comment: Can you please tell me, what would be the impact if the current running replication runs longer than the time allotted between 2 replication runs ? Would the next one try to interfere with current running process or it would see there's already one running, so the next run will not trigger. have been trying to search for it in documenation, but not answer

Comment: Hi, it is the worst possible scenario  to be in . Once I have been in this scenario had sleepless nights for a week. Please remove auto warm up count ,  if already removed try to find out what is the cause . Multiple replications at single time hangs the solr and you have to restart it manually by killing tomcat